# C++ Boost SSL Challenge-Response

Tags: c++, ssl, boost

I'm developing a C++ application that should transmit some data securely.
I want to use SSL over connection, and i decided to ue Boost SSL library.
My question is:

For authentication, i should write myself the challenge-response code ? Or the Boost will do this for me ?

I tried the examples but i don't know if is secure enough.

Also, i should provide the public key ( the .pem file ) ?

```
boost::asio::ssl::context ctx(boost::asio::ssl::context::sslv23);
ctx.load_verify_file("ca.pem");
```

Comment: SSL layer does that for you. Easier to verify using a wireshark when you try to connect to an SSL server socket.

Comment: ok but e.g. my user has an user and a password. to authenticate him by his password i should write myself a challenge-response no ?